# Any Benefit to Hardware Acceleration if Blitting Raw Pixels

Tags: opengl, graphics

I understand that the GPU is very efficient at turning Triangles into pixel data that can be displayed on the screen. What I am wondering is: assuming I already have the raw pixel data and don't need to do any processing on it, is there any benefit to hardware acceleration, instead of just blitting those bits directly to the screen? Given that no primitive to pixel processing needs to occur on the shaders, just a raw copy from a buffer to the screen, is there any benefit to using the GPU to accelerate the blit, given the overhead in sending data from the CPU to the GPU? Thanks!

Apparently, the Windows Blt functions actually use hardware acceleration where possible, so presumably it does help. But, I don't understand how a GPU speeds up a raw copy where no processing is necessary. Presumably, a GPU can copy larger blocks of memory at a time due to its use of SIMD and multi-threading, but since the CPU first needs to waste time sending the pixels from the CPU to the GPU, isn't there a performance cost incurred anyway?

To put it into context, say I just had a bitmap harcoded into memory, and needed to display it by just copying from the bitmap 1 to 1, eg: no raster ops, is there any reason for sending that data to the GPU, given the overhead of data transfer over the PCIe Bus? If so, why?

Sorry, if the question is trivial to those who know a lot about these things. I'm pretty new to Graphics Programming, and want to get a conceptual model in my mind about the cost of CPU-GPU transfer vs the advantage of being able to blit pixels to the screen in a more parallel manner. I'm also curious about how a GPU even optimizes blitting from a Device Dependent Bitmap, given that it should be nothing more than a simple memory to memory copy, if no color translations, resizes, etc need to be made

Thanks to anyone who answers this!

Comment: I read another stack overflow answer and saw something that helped alleviate a few of my doubts:

"The window manager needs to deal with many applications all drawing their own thing, and composite that into one image that gets sent to the monitor. Having the CPU draw each window pixel-by-pixel into the output buffer would be comparatively slow, but the GPU (by virtue of its parallel hardware) can composite images very quickly."

is this what windows means by hardware accelerating bit blits using the GPU?

Comment: I think your premise is wrong to begin with. There is not blitting to "the screen". You blit to the framebuffer, so some memory. And that memory is managed by the GPU. "given the overhead in sending data from the CPU to the GPU" you always have to send the data to the GPU if you want it to appear on the screen.

Comment: understood. that's super useful info. so in that case what types of things would the GPU actually do to hardware accelerate a blit, if it has to be done by the GPU anyway. Is it just a matter of if it has special hardware to accomadate Raster Operations while blitting, etc? Because MSDN says BitBlt may be hardware accelerated if supported by GPU drivers.

Comment: In your case, without pixels transformations, using OS commands or GL commands yields to the same background job: transfer from RAM to GPU memory buffer. No difference in performance, at least not easy to tell.